# Seeking parcel boundaries data for Germany or Sweden?

Tags: data, parcel, germany, sweden

I'm trying to find parcel data (property boundaries) in a GIS format.

I tried googling and nothing is coming up.

I would pay for a vendor like CoreLogic or ReportAll that have parcel data only in the US.

Anyone know anything about parcel boundary in Europe.

Comment: By parcels I mean the property boundary. Below is an example of parcels. It's a boundary of property. It has information like, who owns the property, Type of Property, Address of it , ect
https://reportallusa.com/solutions/overlay/mapbox-leaflet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [INSPIRE Geportal](https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/results.html?country=de&view=details&theme=cp) may give you some of the documents you're searching for.

[image]